# How to addSelectHandler to TabitemConfig Gxt3?

Tags: java, gwt, sencha-architect

I'am working in GXT3 project and i need to add a SelectEvent to TabItemConfig in TabPanel. For example, we can't go to another tabItem if the form in current tabItem doesnt't validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use

```
        TabPanel panel;
        panel.addBeforeSelectionHandler(new BeforeSelectionHandler<Widget>() {

            @Override
            public void onBeforeSelection(BeforeSelectionEvent<Widget> event) {
                //some condition
                event.cancel();
            }
        });
```

you can get event.getItem() and do validation of current tabItem